# Using MigLayout in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout, miglayout

I'm curious as to how I can use MigLayout to evenly distribute components on a grid when placing the components:

For example, if I were to place FOUR JRadioButtons in a ButtonGroup to span 3 rows and 2 columns (2, 3), and subsequently placed THREE JButtons, the distribution is weighted unequally, I would end up with this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/iGayxn4.png]

As seen in the image, A and B are the same size and C holds the remaining space: I would prefer A, B, C to be equal thirds vertically.

If this is possible in GridBagLayout I can utilize that as well, however I run into the same issue with either layout.

Here lies an example of trying to further implement this in an application [image: https://i.imgur.com/b3YrVCF.png]

(I'd prefer to have all buttons disregarding the ButtonGroups, the decimal, and equals to be the same size)

Much thanks.

EDIT: (Thanks, to Andrew for the fixes) Here's the example code of adding the buttons using MigLayout:

```
    bp.add(buttonGroup1, "grow, span 2 3");
    bp.add(btnQuot );
    bp.add(btnMod);
    bp.add(btnA);
    bp.add(emptyBtn1, "grow");
    bp.add(emptyBtn2, "grow");
    bp.add(emptyBtn3, "grow");
    bp.add(emptyBtn4, "grow");
    bp.add(emptyBtn5, "grow, wrap");
    bp.add(emptyBtn6, "grow");
    bp.add(emptyBtn7, "grow");
    bp.add(btnB, "grow");
    bp.add(btnBackSpace);
    bp.add(btnClrEntr);
    bp.add(btnClear);
    bp.add(btnPlMns);
    bp.add(btnSqrt, "grow,wrap");
    bp.add(emptyBtn8, "grow");
    bp.add(emptyBtn9, "grow");
    bp.add(btnC, "grow");
    bp.add(btn7, "grow");
    bp.add(btn8, "grow");
    bp.add(btn9, "grow");
    bp.add(btnDiv, "grow");
    bp.add(btnPerc, "grow, wrap");
    bp.add(buttonGroup2, "span 2 3");
    bp.add(emptyBtn10, "grow");
    bp.add(emptyBtn11, "grow");
    bp.add(btnD, "grow");
    bp.add(btn4, "grow");
    bp.add(btn5, "grow");
    bp.add(btn6);
    bp.add(btnMult, "grow");
    bp.add(btnOneOverX, "wrap");
    bp.add(emptyBtn12, "grow");
    bp.add(emptyBtn13, "grow");
    bp.add(btnE, "grow");
    bp.add(btn1, "grow");
    bp.add(btn2, "grow");
    bp.add(btn3);
    bp.add(btnSub, "grow");
    bp.add(btnEquals, "grow,wrap, span 1 2");
    bp.add(emptyBtn14, "grow");
    bp.add(emptyBtn15, "grow");
    bp.add(btnF, "grow");
    bp.add(btn0, "grow, span 2");
    bp.add(btnDecimal, "grow");
    bp.add(btnPlus, "grow");
```

The issue may very well be trying to represent the button groups as a 2x3 cell, so I will attempt the multiple panels when next possible.

Comment: provide your code and don't use links to pictures, include everything here in your question

Comment: You need to make two panels with the separate layouts. For example you can use `GridLayout` for your radio-button group, `MigLayout` or `GridBagLayout` for your buttons panel and `BorderLayout` to combine all together.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy That does seem to be a better implementation, I assume if I leave the buttonGroups out, the JButtons will be more congruent, will update when implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with MigLayout.  Check out the section on ["Merging and Splitting Cells"](http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf).  Also don't be afraid to use multiple JPanels.

Here's a simplified example of what you're trying to do:

```
public class MigSample
{   
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        // create radio buttons
        JRadioButton radio1 = new JRadioButton("1");
        JRadioButton radio2 = new JRadioButton("2");
        JRadioButton radio3 = new JRadioButton("3");
        JRadioButton radio4 = new JRadioButton("4");

        // create buttons
        JButton buttonA = new JButton("A");
        JButton buttonB = new JButton("B");
        JButton buttonC = new JButton("C");
        JButton buttonD = new JButton("D");
        JButton buttonE = new JButton("=");

        // create the panel that contains the radio buttons
        JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap 1")); // wrap 1 let's us avoid adding the wrap constraing to every component
        radioPanel.add(radio1);
        radioPanel.add(radio2);
        radioPanel.add(radio3);
        radioPanel.add(radio4);

        // create the panel that contains the other buttons
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("filly, wrap 2")); // filly tells it to take up all the vertical space
        // add growy to all components so they will fit the cell height
        buttonPanel.add(buttonA, "growy");
        buttonPanel.add(buttonD, "growy");
        buttonPanel.add(buttonB, "growy");
        buttonPanel.add(buttonE, "span 1 2, growy"); // span 1 2 tells this component to span 1 column and 2 rows
        buttonPanel.add(buttonC, "growy");

        // create the main contentPane
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new MigLayout("filly")); // again, we want to fill the vertical space so the 2 panels will have the same height
        contentPane.add(radioPanel);
        contentPane.add(buttonPanel, "growy");

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  @Amber ! .Just tested the code and it works, I'll try to implement it in my project soon. I was confused on row/column constraints in MigLayout after referring to the whitepaper/quick start guide. I also tried to avoid using multiple panels, as I thought MigLayout made it less likely to require nested panels.

Additionally, I referred to the javadoc/quickstart and it seems sizegroups are used to deal with keeping components the same size, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Size groups are a good idea, especially if you have buttons with text of different lengths. i.e. something like this would make the buttons the same width, whereas without it the buttons would be different sizes:
  contentPane.add(new JButton("hi"), "sg 1");
  contentPane.add(new JButton("hello"), "sg 1");

Comment: I see, so you add the components to a size group when adding each component, and I'm assuming you could do the same for the button height( i.e, solve my question in another way?)

Also, I've pulled Mikael Grev's demo from his github and compiled it:
https://github.com/mikaelgrev/miglayout/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/net/miginfocom/demo/SwingDemo.java

which seems to be pretty useful in learning. 

In any case, that helped me a lot thank you, now I just need to work on getting the event handling down!